# SSRS report stops responding to mouse clicks

Tags: reporting-services, mouseevent, mouse, ssrs-2012

I have a very simple SSRS report with a table control that expands/collapses a details group. After deployment, when the report is rendered in ReportManager in Internet Explorer, the report will allow one mouse click, but any further mouse clicks do nothing.

For example, you can click to expand the Details group of the table. But then clicking to collapse the group does not work. Clicking to sort by a column does nothing, clicking the link to a subreport does nothing, even clicking on the report scroll bar to see the bottom of the page does nothing. If any of these mouse clicks were attempted immediately after the report is rendered (i.e. if it is the first mouse click), then they work. After the first mouse click, no further mouse click do anything.

This is obviously a major problem - we cannot put the reports into production in this state.

I have found that if I click the button which shows or hides the report parameters pane, then the report will then allow further mouse clicks. While this is a work-around for development, it will be unacceptable for the users to have to do this.

Any advice on how to solve this would be welcome.

This is on SSRS 2012 with Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: have you checked F12 -> console for JS error messages in IE?

Comment: F12 developer tools are disabled on my computer, so I am unable to check this.

Comment: does this happen only in IE, what about FF or Chrome?

Comment: My PC is locked down; I am not able to install any other browser, unfortunately.